# How to add indent such that the section is shown in the right of page number?

Tags: sectioning, header-footer, page-numbering

```
\documentclass[twoside,11pt]{book}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,papersize={15.5cm,23.5cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,xcolor,lipsum}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\colorlet{myfancycolor}{black}

\fancypagestyle{mystyle}{
    \renewcommand*\headrulewidth{1pt}
    \fancyhead[OR]{%
        \color{myfancycolor}\rule{2em}{2em}\raisebox{0.5em}{\hspace{-2em}\color{white}\makebox[2em][c]{\textsf{\thepage}}}%
        \vspace*{-0.8em}%
    }
    \fancyhead[OL]{%
        \leftmark
    }    
    \fancyhead[EL]{%
        \color{myfancycolor}\rule{2em}{2em}\raisebox{0.5em}{\hspace{-2em}\color{white}\makebox[2em][c]{\textsf{\thepage}}}%
        \vspace*{-0.8em}%
    }   
    \fancyhead[ER]{%
        \rightmark
    }
}


\pagestyle{mystyle}
\begin{document}
    \chapter{CHAPTER ONE}
    \section{Numerical Solution for Diffusion Equation with Neumann Boundary
         Condition}
     \lipsum[1-4]
\end{document}
```

I have long section title. I use "black box" to show the page number. In header, the section is show behind of page number. How to add indent such that the section is show in the right of page number?

[image]

Comment: A simple solution would be to add `\small` before `\rightmark`. This helps until you get even bigger section titles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem for long section titles is addressed in the [`fancyhdr`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) documentation.

According to that, you may employ one of the three solution.

1. You can use the optional argument in the `\section` command to insert a shorter title that will appear on the header. Code:

```
\documentclass[twoside,11pt]{book}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,papersize={15.5cm,23.5cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,xcolor,lipsum}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\colorlet{myfancycolor}{black}

\fancypagestyle{mystyle}{
    \renewcommand*\headrulewidth{1pt}
    \fancyhead[OR]{%
        \color{myfancycolor}\rule{2em}{2em}\raisebox{0.5em}{\hspace{-2em}\color{white}\makebox[2em][c]{\textsf{\thepage}}}%
        \vspace*{-0.8em}%
    }
    \fancyhead[OL]{%
        \leftmark
    }    
    \fancyhead[EL]{%
        \color{myfancycolor}\rule{2em}{2em}\raisebox{0.5em}{\hspace{-2em}\color{white}\makebox[2em][c]{\textsf{\thepage}}}%
        \vspace*{-0.8em}%
    }   
    \fancyhead[ER]{%
        \rightmark
    }
}


\pagestyle{mystyle}
\begin{document}
    \chapter{CHAPTER ONE}
    \section[Numerical Solution]{Numerical Solution for Diffusion Equation with Neumann Boundary
         Condition}
    \lipsum[1-4]
\end{document}
```

[image]

2. You can truncate the section title using the [`truncate`](https://ctan.org/pkg/truncate) package. Code:

```
\documentclass[twoside,11pt]{book}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,papersize={15.5cm,23.5cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,xcolor,lipsum}
\usepackage[fit]{truncate} %--> Added
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\colorlet{myfancycolor}{black}

\fancypagestyle{mystyle}{
    \renewcommand*\headrulewidth{1pt}
    \fancyhead[OR]{%
        \color{myfancycolor}\rule{2em}{2em}\raisebox{0.5em}{\hspace{-2em}\color{white}\makebox[2em][c]{\textsf{\thepage}}}%
        \vspace*{-0.8em}%
    }
    \fancyhead[OL]{%
        \leftmark
    }    
    \fancyhead[EL]{%
        \color{myfancycolor}\rule{2em}{2em}\raisebox{0.5em}{\hspace{-2em}\color{white}\makebox[2em][c]{\textsf{\thepage}}}%
        \vspace*{-0.8em}%
    }   
    \fancyhead[ER]{%
        \truncate{0.9\headwidth}{\rightmark} %--> changed
    }
}


\pagestyle{mystyle}
\begin{document}
    \chapter{CHAPTER ONE}
    \section{Numerical Solution for Diffusion Equation with Neumann Boundary Condition}
    \lipsum[1-4]
\end{document}
```

[image]

3. Use the `\sectionmark` command explicitly to specify a shorter title for header. To appear the title correctly in every possible scenario and in the TOC, you need to use it multiple times with the optional argument of the `\section` command. So, the package author proposed to use a macro like this `\newcommand{\LongSection}[2]{\section[#1]{#1\sectionmark{#2}}\sectionmark{#2}}`. Code:

```
\documentclass[twoside,11pt]{book}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,papersize={15.5cm,23.5cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,xcolor,lipsum}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\colorlet{myfancycolor}{black}

\fancypagestyle{mystyle}{
    \renewcommand*\headrulewidth{1pt}
    \fancyhead[OR]{%
        \color{myfancycolor}\rule{2em}{2em}\raisebox{0.5em}{\hspace{-2em}\color{white}\makebox[2em][c]{\textsf{\thepage}}}%
        \vspace*{-0.8em}%
    }
    \fancyhead[OL]{%
        \leftmark
    }    
    \fancyhead[EL]{%
        \color{myfancycolor}\rule{2em}{2em}\raisebox{0.5em}{\hspace{-2em}\color{white}\makebox[2em][c]{\textsf{\thepage}}}%
        \vspace*{-0.8em}%
    }   
    \fancyhead[ER]{%
        \rightmark
    }
}

\newcommand{\LongSection}[2]{\section[#1]{#1\sectionmark{#2}}\sectionmark{#2}}


\pagestyle{mystyle}
\begin{document}
    \chapter{CHAPTER ONE}
    \LongSection{Numerical Solution for Diffusion Equation with Neumann Boundary Condition}{Numerical Solution}
     \lipsum[1-4]
\end{document}
```

[image]